# How do you loop an array and append it to a div?

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, append

I'm trying to create an array and have it loop through the array and append it to a div.

HTML/PHP:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-3">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').append("
        <div class='CLASS_NAME_HERE'>
            <span class='vertical-align-middle'></span>
            <img src='IMG_HERE'>
        </div>
        <div class='filter-label'>LABEL_HERE</div>");
});}
```

JS ARRAY

```
var arrayTest= [
    {className: "class-01", urlSrc: "www.url01.com", labelName: "01 Label Name"},
    {className: "class-02", urlSrc: "www.url02.com", labelName: "02 Label Name"},
    {className: "class-03", urlSrc: "www.url03.com", labelName: "03 Label Name"},
]
```

Basically, it would loop through the array and append each one to look like this:

```
<li id="menu-item-1">
    <a href="#">
        <div class='class-01'>
            <span class='vertical-align-middle'></span>
            <img src='www.url01.com'>
        </div>
        <div class='filter-label'>01 Label Name</div>");
    </a>
</li>
```

I haven't been able to work out the loop properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop the array. Using [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you can use the two arguments that are provided:

- `item`
- `index`.

At each loop iteration, using the `item`, you can access the objects properties like `className`, `urlSrc` and `labelName`.

Using the `index`, you can target the right `a` element with the [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

You will also notice the use of [templating literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insrt the variables in the string to append.

```js
var arrayTest = [
  {
    className: "class-01",
    urlSrc: "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Image 1",
    labelName: "01 Label Name"
  },
  {
    className: "class-02",
    urlSrc: "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Image 2",
    labelName: "02 Label Name"
  },
  { className: "class-03",
   urlSrc: "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Image 3",
   labelName: "03 Label Name"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function () {
  arrayTest.forEach(function (item, index) {
    $("#menu a").eq(index).append(
`<div class="${item.className}">
  <span class='vertical-align-middle'></span>
  <img src="${item.urlSrc}">
</div>
<div class='filter-label'>${item.labelName}</div>`
    );
  });
});
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-1">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-2">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-3">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```